# Adding pinch-zoomable div image to a non-scalable viewport on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, touch

Consider the following viewport meta tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui" />
```

The content on the page is non-scalable and mobile responsive. Sometimes, I need to overlay a large image on top of it, and allow the user to pinch-zoom that image.

```
#overlay_div {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #dddddd;
    z-index: 550000;
    overflow: scroll;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

<div id="overlay_div">
    <img src="largeimage.jpg" width="100%">
</div>
```

Currently, I am aware of two possible options:

1. Programmatically change the viewport meta to allow user scaling (possible cross-browser implications, also causes content underneath to scale which is not desirable)
2. Use hammer.js to manually handle the pinch event and scale the div/image accordingly (seems very complex possible compatibility implications).

Does anyone know the proper way to do this, especially for cross-browser compatibility? I am hoping there may be a simple CSS solution.

Thanks

Comment: I hope no-one who wears glasses ever tries to use this page,,,because if they can't scale...they won't be able to read it. That's why it's not a recommended property.

Comment: millikenchemical.com on a mobile device is non-scalable, but can be read. From my understanding, this is where the web is headed. Mobile friendly, responsive content. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure it's your case but usually I prefer to make image a link (a) to original image. Mobile browsers can handle this situation opening image in `full screen` mode. Then user can do whatever he wants with the image or can go back to main page.

Comment: Can you give any details on this `full screen mode` you speak of? Is this a javascript or css thing?

Comment: @MarksCode, I'm talking about opening image just in a browser without any addons/js code. Most browsers, especially mobiles, can handle this very well.

Comment: ah.. too bad pinch and zoom doesn't work for this :(

Comment: works for me on multiple android devices (on firefox and chrome), I'm not sure about other platforms.

Comment: If you implement navigation in an Cordova app, there's no place to put the "Back" button. I absolutely sure that's Apple's guilt, ignoring the necessity of that important navigation button. But we cannot change that. So the solution is only appropriate for web apps and not Cordova apps.

Answer (score 0):

In general I would go with a zoomable version like @Paulie_D recommended; so use this on all of your pages:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Here is [Google´s recommendation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/set-the-viewport).

If you really have no other choice, I would recommend to open the image in the same browser tab/window with the `meta` tag shown above and a *back* link for navigation. So the *native* pinch-zoom is available.

This is an example for such an implementation (you need a mobile user agent): https://m.notebooksbilliger.de/notebooks/hp+compaq+15+h024sg

Comment: Hmmmm... It is a map underneath, which is why I have the user scaling disabled. When you pinch the map zooms. Maybe I could enable scaling using your viewport meta tag and try to remove the events that would cause the map div underneath to scale... I dunno. Thanks

Comment: openlayers with a google map layer... I tried hammer.js but am having trouble with windows phones. I think maybe the best option at this point is to redirect to a new page, and use window.location.back() to get back quickly.

Comment: think there is any way to accomplish this with an iframe?

Comment: @wayofthefuture I'm interested in this approach because the browser already knows how to pinch-zoom on the page, so why use complicated javascript libraries?  But, I want to be able to pinch zoom on a particular *element*.